# How to insert comment in xml generated by serializer?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I have some class, for example:

```
Public Class MyClass
  Public Property MyProperty As Integer = 1
End Class
```

Serializer (Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer) creates XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyProperty>1</MyProperty>
</MyClass>
```

How I can get from serializer somthing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Use positive values less than 10 -->
    <MyProperty>1</MyProperty>
 </MyClass>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385921/how-to-write-a-comment-to-an-xml-file-when-using-the-xmlserializer)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of 
[XmlComment(Value = "Your Comment")] attribute